# import jpg image in Reactjs with NextJS some images import return long string

Tags: reactjs, import, next.js, srcset

I am importing images in different scales and show them in my react app

some images are import correctly,
but some get really long and "strange" string name instead of their regular file name

for example

```
import generator from '../images/generators/generator-rental.jpg';
import generatorw205 from '../images/generators/generator-rental@0,4x.jpg'; 
import generatorw384 from '../images/generators/generator-rental@0,75x.jpg';
```

when I put 3 of them together in `srcSet` the smallest image get the long string.

the generatorw205 and generatorw384 are imported correctly and shown with this src property:

```
"/_next/static/images/generator-rental-9f9671c1ae14a9abd201cce092b95c0d.jpg 512w"
```

and

```
/_next/static/images/generator-rental@0,75x-0ff42525965adeb23850ef8dacd34c50.jpg 384w,
```

but the first image get this string:

```
data:image/jpeg;base64,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 205w,
```

And this is my next.config.js file:

```
const withImages = require('next-images')
const withPlugins = require("next-compose-plugins");
const optimizedImages = require("next-optimized-images");
const withBundleAnalyzer = require('@next/bundle-analyzer')({
    enabled: process.env.ANALYZE === 'true'
  })

module.exports = withPlugins(
    [
        [optimizedImages, {

        }],
        [withBundleAnalyzer, {
            
        }]
    ]
);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update**

For  *next-optimized-images*. The plugin has similar config - https://github.com/cyrilwanner/next-optimized-images#inline

```
module.exports = withPlugins(
    [
        [optimizedImages, {
           inlineImageLimit:4096
        }],
        [withBundleAnalyzer, {
            
        }]
    ]
);
```

> some images are import correctly, but some get really long and "strange" string name instead of their regular file name

The *strange* string name is the [base64](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Basics_of_HTTP/Data_URIs) representation that can be supplied to data url's by employing this technique you can avoid additional http downloads from the server.

Comment: Hi, thank you, it sounds like you are right, I have edited and added my next.config.js code because I am not using "next-images" but "optimizedImages" package, do you know how I can set it in order for that fix?

Comment: Edited for `next-optimized-images`